# How to create index for the following kind of data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing

```
db.test.insert({a:1, b:[1])
db.test.insert({a:1, b: 1})
db.test.insert({a:[1], b: 1})
db.test.insert({a:[1], b: [1]})
```

what should be a right way to index the fields so that i can query over a and b?

Answer (score 1):

```
{ _id: 1, a: [1, 2], b: 1, category: "A array" }
{ _id: 2, a: 1, b: [1, 2], category: "B array" }
```

> A compound multikey index { a: 1, b: 1 } is permissible since for each
> document, only one field indexed by the compound multikey index is an
> array; i.e. no document contains array values for both a and b fields.
>
> However, after creating the compound multikey index, if you attempt to
> insert a document where both a and b fields are arrays, MongoDB will
> fail the insert.

---- [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/)

*But one of your doc's a & b both contain array.*

Comment: So for this kind of document scopes , any index is not possible ?

Comment: Documentation says so.